# How to check if a number can be represented as a sum of some given numbers

Tags: numbers, sum

I've got a list of some integers, e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]`
And I've another integer (`N`). For example, `N = 19`.

I want to check if my integer can be represented as a sum of any amount of numbers in my list:

```
19 = 10 + 5 + 4
```

or

```
19 = 10 + 4 + 3 + 2
```

Every number from the list can be used only once. `N` can raise up to 2 thousand or more. Size of the list can reach 200 integers.

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Have you tried using `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: No, but can it solve my problem? I'll try it now, thanks

Comment: This is basically the [0-1 Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is NP-complete.  So the answer to your question is, in a sense, "no." There is no good way to solve this problem. You'll find some bad ways to solve it if you follow that link.

Comment: Nope, itertools will not help you. I disagree wholeheartedly with @MartijnPieters on this one, anything (barring brute force of course) solving this is sufficiently complex that even a starting algorithm is tricky to get. And what use is posting yet another brute-force solution when that isn't desired. However, in it's current form, I doubt a lot of answers will come here. Possibly/perhaps there's more help at http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @histocrat: do you perhaps have any insight how the difference between `<=` (knapsack) & `=` (current question) may alter this problem?

Comment: @Wrikken, I was hinting at writing a simple brute force solution using that function from itertools, but was thinking this was tagged as python

Comment: @Wrikken: According to the page, setting it to `=` makes it the [Subset-sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  I hadn't heard that term before, but apparently it remains NP-Complete.

Comment: Hehe, was looking for it, but somehow couldn't find it.. but indeed, last words on the knapsack page, and even psuedo-code for an [approximate algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm) which given the conditions there (small numbers, non-negative, _"If any sum of the numbers can be specified with at most P bits, then solving the problem approximately with c = 2^−P is equivalent to solving it exactly."_.... I think we have our exact answer to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute force approach requires generating 2^(array_size)-1 subsets to be summed and compared against target `N`.

The run time can be dramatically improved by simply splitting the problem in two. Store, in sets, all of the possible sums for one half of the array and the other half separately. It can now be determined by checking for every number `n` in one set if the complement`N`-`n` exists in the other set.

This optimization brings the complexity down to approximately: `2^(array_size/2)-1+2^(array_size/2)-1=2^(array_size/2 + 1)-2`
Half of the original.

Here is a c++ implementation using this idea.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
bool sum_search(vector<int> myarray, int N) {
        //values for splitting the array in two
        int right=myarray.size()-1,middle=(myarray.size()-1)/2;

        set<int> all_possible_sums1,all_possible_sums2;

        //iterate over the first half of the array
        for(int i=0;i<middle;i++) {
            //buffer set that will hold new possible sums
            set<int> buffer_set;

            //every value currently in the set is used to make new possible sums
            for(set<int>::iterator set_iterator=all_possible_sums1.begin();set_iterator!=all_possible_sums1.end();set_iterator++) 
                buffer_set.insert(myarray[i]+*set_iterator);

            all_possible_sums1.insert(myarray[i]);

            //transfer buffer into the main set
            for(set<int>::iterator set_iterator=buffer_set.begin();set_iterator!=buffer_set.end();set_iterator++) 
                all_possible_sums1.insert(*set_iterator);
        } 

        //iterator over the second half of the array
        for(int i=middle;i<right+1;i++) {
            set<int> buffer_set;    

            for(set<int>::iterator set_iterator=all_possible_sums2.begin();set_iterator!=all_possible_sums2.end();set_iterator++)   
                buffer_set.insert(myarray[i]+*set_iterator);

            all_possible_sums2.insert(myarray[i]);

            for(set<int>::iterator set_iterator=buffer_set.begin();set_iterator!=buffer_set.end();set_iterator++) 
                all_possible_sums2.insert(*set_iterator);
        }

        //for every element in the first set, check if the the second set has the complemenent to make N
        for(set<int>::iterator set_iterator=all_possible_sums1.begin();set_iterator!=all_possible_sums1.end();set_iterator++)  
            if(all_possible_sums2.find(N-*set_iterator)!=all_possible_sums2.end()) 
                return true;                                       
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Marking this as an accepted answer. I've also posted Python implementations for your approach and for the bruteforce as well as their time comparison. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

4 years and a half later, this question is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45395355/1895283) by Jonathan.
I want to post two implementations (bruteforce and Jonathan's) in Python and their performance comparison.

```python
def check_sum_bruteforce(numbers, n):
    # This bruteforce approach can be improved (for some cases) by
    # returning True as soon as the needed sum is found;

    sums = []

    for number in numbers:
        for sum_ in sums[:]:
            sums.append(sum_ + number)

        sums.append(number)

    return n in sums


def check_sum_optimized(numbers, n):
    sums1, sums2 = [], []
    numbers1 = numbers[:len(numbers) // 2]
    numbers2 = numbers[len(numbers) // 2:]

    for sums, numbers_ in ((sums1, numbers1), (sums2, numbers2)):
        for number in numbers_:
            for sum_ in sums[:]:
                sums.append(sum_ + number)

            sums.append(number)

    for sum_ in sums1:
        if n - sum_ in sums2:
            return True

    return False


assert check_sum_bruteforce([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10], 19)
assert check_sum_optimized([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10], 19)

import timeit

print(
    "Bruteforce approach (10000 times):",
    timeit.timeit(
        'check_sum_bruteforce([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 200)',
        number=10000,
        globals=globals()
    )
)

print(
    "Optimized approach by Jonathan (10000 times):",
    timeit.timeit(
        'check_sum_optimized([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 200)',
        number=10000,
        globals=globals()
    )
)
```

Output (the float numbers are seconds):

```
Bruteforce approach (10000 times): 1.830944365834205
Optimized approach by Jonathan (10000 times): 0.34162875449254027
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly and brute force approach:

```
 a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
 b = []
 a.size.times do |c|
    b << a.combination(c).select{|d| d.reduce(&:+) == 19 }
 end
 puts b.flatten(1).inspect
```